# Hp psc 1210 all-in-one printer and windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have recently upgraded my computer from windows xp to w-7.  Trying to use my HP psc1210 all in one printer with w-7 but can not find driver

Answer (score 1):

According to [HP Support](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-psc-1200-all-in-one-printer-series/90763/model/90765#Z7_3054ICK0K8UDA0AQC11TA930C7) to use the PSC 1210 All-in-One Printer, you must use the drivers provided with Windows 7.

If this printer is not available for you to select during the installation process, use [Windows Update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/find-and-install-printer-drivers) to get all the updated drivers.